# Permission denied to write to my own files

Tags: permissions, users

I am not being given permission to write to files I created.  I am not allowed to edit any files of any kind anywhere in any directory.

Comment: My `pathlld` script ( https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld.git - Bash script to answer "Why can't I read/write that file?" ) will help you.

Comment: Checked the basics already? `ls -la [folder]`, `mount` says the fs is writeable?

Comment: You only can read/write in folders under your home folder. Do you have this issue suddenly? Did something happen before you got the issue? Check the output of the commands `id`, `ls -l /home` and `ls -l /home/$USER` to find out if permissions are correct. Check the output of `mount` to see whether the partition containing your home folder is correctly mounted